# Escape bad characters for iOS UILabel?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

I'm feeding some NSString data (forum posts queried from my website) into a UILabel as part of my first app.  Thing is, sometimes, depending on the content of the post, the Label goes entirely blank.  I've tinkered enough to discern that there are certain characters that cause the problem, but I can't quite pin down the full set.

Is there a collected list of character types to watch out for with this kind of thing?  And even better, is there a method for escaping them, or automatically converting them into something more acceptable?

Thank you for helping out a n00b!

Comment: Can you provide an example of these bad characters?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have whitespace or new line in your string:

Try this:

```
NSString* labelText = [stringFromWebsite stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

Comment: Are spaces and new lines not allowed in `UILabel`s then?

Comment: they are allowed, but if you have escape chars at the begining of your string, and if you have set your uilabel to show only 1 line, then you'll see an empty label because it will be only showing the first line, which is an empty line because of the escape char. I'd just trim the string, and then let uilabel do the job, you can set uilabel to show multiple lines and also its text alignment, etc..

Comment: Also, if you are showing text with multiple lines, i'd recommend you to use uitextfield, instead of uilabel. as you can understand form its name, ui label is intended for showing things like labels, and text field is more likely for showing "text fields". if you dont want user to be able the click or change textfields content, you can set its "userinteractionenabled" to false.

Comment: I still don't understand how stripping the spaces and newlines is going to remove the "escape characters"?

Comment: I changed the UILabel to a UITextView, but it doesn't seem to be helping.  The problem is that one individual post in the NSMutableDictionary that I'm pulling my info from can blank out every TextView in the table.  For example: [works](http://edgeworksent.com/pic1.png) vs [doesn't work](http://edgeworksent.com/pic2.png).  I know it's an individual post because I can isolate them, and with enough tinkering I can figure out what character was the problem and delete it and then the whole table starts working, but I couldn't possibly do that for every post on the whole forum...  Any ideas?

Comment: A CLUE!  Debugging shows that the NSMutableDictionary isn't populating at all when the bad post is included.  Is there a character or character type that interferes with an NSMutableDictionary, or that could invalidate the plist that I'm generating it from?  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to give you some clue even you haven't put piece of code here in your question.

You should firstly try to encode that coming String by using appropriate method like `encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` and still and try to set decoded string to your `UIlabel`.

Another alternative is that you can create some `regex` for `filtering` purpose of that coming string. you can find many of similar thread over the google.

Comment: I didn't post my code because there's no relevant code to post.  The only thing I'm doing is `[postBody setText:postBodyText];`.  The problem is with the source information, and as I said, I don't know what part specifically because that's what I'm asking.  

But thanks for the ideas!